# SSRS php library SetItemDataSources, The required field Item is missing from the input structure

Tags: c#, php, reporting-services

In PHP, 
Using SSRS Reporting services library installed via composer with: chriskl/phpssrs": "^0.1.2

After having successfully called `CreateCatalogItem(...)`, and seeing that the report exists in SQL Server Reporting Services, I am encountering an error (message and stack trace listed below) when running `SetItemDataSources(...)`.

A colleague is able to run the call correctly, however 2 other environments also fail with the same error.  So this looks like could be an environment issue, and asking for any help pointing us towards what that might be, or otherwise.

The error states

> "The required field Item is missing from the input structure"

so we have considered that it could be a versioning issue whereby one version of the SSRS service is looking for an Item field and the library we're using is not supplying it.

The contents of the SOAP call contain no element named Item.

Here is the code that is failing:

```
$connName = 'MyConnName';

$dsd = new DataSourceDefinition(
    'SQL',          //Extension
    null,           //ConnectString
    true,           //UseOriginalConnectString
    true,           //$OriginalConnectStringExpressionBased
    'Integrated',   //$CredentialRetrieval
    false,          //$WindowsCredentials
    false,          //$ImpersonateUser
    "Specify a user name and password for data source {$connName}:",    //$Prompt
    null,           //$UserName
    null,           //Password
    true            //Enabled
);

$ds = new DataSource(
        $connName,
        null,
        null,
        $dsd
);

$sids = new SetItemDataSources($path . $name, [$ds]);

$rs->SetItemDataSources($sids);
```

This is the error (exception) generated from the call:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The required field Item is missing from the input structure. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.MissingElementException: The required field Item is missing from the input structure. at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetItemDataSources(String Item, DataSource[] DataSources, Guid batchId) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetItemDataSources(String Item, DataSource[] DataSources) at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDataSources(String ItemPath, DataSource[] DataSources)